# Is an aircraft considered experimental if built when having A&P licence?

Tags: faa-regulations, experimental-aircraft, airframe-and-powerplant, amateur-experimental

I got my Airframe and Powerplant while in the Army 20 years ago, never used it after I got out. If I built an aircraft from scratch would it be considered amature experimental?

Comment: I'm no expert, but I believe that until it receives CAA approval, _every_ aircraft is consider experimental. Even Dick Rutan's aircraft were consider experimental until they received regulatory approval.

Comment: If you haven't used your A&P in 20 years I doubt it would be considered valid.

Comment: A&P doesn't expire.... your just considered "not current" you have to have 6 months/1000 hours to be brought back to current under someone with an A&P so they can sign off on your work and hours.

Comment: When you complete the airplane the FAA issues you a "Repairman's Certificate" that gives you the authority of an AI regardless of whether you have an A&P or not.Subsequent purchasers of Experimentals can also get them now by taking a little course. The rules in Canada where I am are pretty liberal on that. All maintenance work, incl structural repairs and engine rebuilds, etc, are signed off by whomever's name is on the C of R, whether they are the original builder or subsequent owner. If I want to fly in transponder airspace, though, I have to have my encoder signed off by an AMO every 2 yrs.

Comment: @JohnK - as an subsequent owner of a experimental aircraft, I'd appreciate knowing more about the "little course" you're referring to to get a Repairman Certificate.

Comment: @user2070305 My mistake it only applies to Light Sport airplanes.  Amatuer builts still only give it to the original builder, so as subsequent purchaser you can do everything but the annual and you need an A&P (doesn't have to be an AI) to sign the annual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, even if you are a certified A&P, any aircraft you build from scratch or a kit is considered an "amateur built" experimental. Even long running kits like Vans RV series are considered experimental. All aircraft are experimental until they receive certification from the FAA, which isn't economic for home builts.

It's considered "amateur built" because to the FAA, there are two classes of build, a certified aircraft in an assembly process in a factory, and amateurs.

Comment: From a strict legal sense the person who constructs 51% of the airplane is the "manufacturer".

Comment: And the manufacturer requires a Manufacturer’s Certificate…

Comment: Talking 100% and thank you. Just wanted to be sure before I put my self in bankruptcy and tried to fly with untested wings.